# How to use application buttons that are under the usual on-screen buttons (Back/Home/Tiled apps)

Tags: xiaomi, navigation-bar

Many sites show buttons to accept/reject the cookie policy at the bottom of the screen. But on my phone (Xiaomi Note 7, Android 10) this puts them under the on-screen-buttons:

[image]

It seems that everything under the faint/thin line at the bottom is out of reach, either nothing happens or the on-screen buttons take precedence (on sites with thicker buttons, I can tap the button above the line)

Is there a way to avoid or mitigate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoom in the webpage near the navigation bar and than drag the content to the middle of the screen or wherever you are comfortable in accessing it. If you can't zoom in, then enable Force Zoom in your browser settings.  Chrome and Firefox both offer force zoom in their settings. Once enabled, zoom in would work on any site.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on desktop site mode in your browser

Comment: How would that solve the problem?

Comment: @Firelord As far as my tests go it does, because in that case the site doesn't extend in the on-creen buttons area.

Comment: Works OK in the regular browser, but it turns out that my problem is mostly with sites displayed in the Reddit app and there is no such option.